# react-select custom heading

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How to set custom component for selected value with react select, i was able to customize options but how about selected option itself, would be smart to have the same selected component as options too, any ideas?

```
<Select 
 components={{ Option: CustomOption }}
 options={options} 
 styles={customStyles} 
/>;
```

Component:

```
    const CustomOption =  ({ value, label, innerProps, innerRef }) => (
        <div ref={innerRef {...innerProps}>
        <img src={label === 'En' ? pngEn : label === 'Ru' ? pngRu : pngLt} />
       <div>{label}</div>
</div>
);
```

Edit, options bellow, i want to the flag would be seen then option is selected, thats probably because of custom options:

```
const options = [
  { value: "lt", label: "Lt" },
  { value: "en", label: "En" },
  { value: "ru", label: "Ru" },
];
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share some design or exact idea of the customization you want to achieve ? thanks

Comment: @Laura  attached image. flag icon doesn't appear then item is selected.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way to do it is to use a custom `Option` component exactly the way you did and storing an extra props inside your `options` to have the corresponding picture you want to display.

Below an example with `react-icons` library instead of using an image but the idea is the same:

```
const Option = props => {
  const CComponent = props.data.icon;
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <CComponent />
      <components.Option {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};
const options = [
  { label: "Option 1", value: 1, icon: FaOpera },
  { label: "Option 2", value: 2, icon: FaFirefox },
  { label: "Option 3", value: 3, icon: FaInternetExplorer }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={options} components={{ Option }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-custom-option-rendering-zq54y).